# Angularjs: why the $watch is execute first before other function

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, watch

Form what I know the function should be from top to bottom. But in this code, the watch will execute first than the getOrders function. Anyone have the solution to let the getOrders function to be execute first?

```
 $scope.getOrders=function () {
        OrderService.getOrders(1)
        .success(function (ords) {
            if (angular.isArray(ords)) {
                $scope.Orders = ords;
                console.log("testing2");
                console.log("testing 3"+$scope.Orders);
            } else {
                $scope.Orders = [ords];
                console.log("testing");
            }

            $scope.dateT = true;
            $scope.StatusEnum = { 10: "Pending", 20: "Processing", 30: "Ready to Shipping", 40: "Cancelled" };

        }).error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
    }
//Here edited, I got add in but still cant
$scope.getOrders();
$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {

            var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage), end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
            //$scope.filteredTodos = $scope.Orders.slice(begin, end);
            console.log("testing" + $scope.Orders);
        },1);
```

But the result i saw in console is like this
[image]

Comment: How is `getOrders` executed?

Comment: I got execute it before the $watch, but it still the same.
$scope.getOrders();

$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {});

no sure how to ng-bind.

Comment: Of course, this is expected behaviour, nothing wrong with it. Just check for data existence in watch.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare **new value** with **old value** and if it is different, only then it is executed , like this:

```
$scope.$watch('your variable', function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(newValue != oldValue){
         //execute your code here 
     }
  }, true);
```

Comment: but I want it to execute later. mean before the watch execute, let the getOrders() to execute first

Comment: why dont you update the currentPage + numPerPage into the 'success'(so the watch is going to execute) function and create a new variable , like $scope.total = currentPage + numPerPage; and put 'total' inside the watch?

Answer (score 0):

You are logging it incorrectly, your `testing2` and `testing 3` log calls are not from `getOrders` function but from a success callback. Also you are not logging the `$watch` function but you are logging callback which is executed when the values in `currentPage + numPerPage` expression change. The `getOrders` and `$watch` functions are executed as you would expect, but the callbacks are not executed in that order.

If you want for some code to execute when the orders are returned you should execute it in the `success` callback, like this:

```
$scope.getOrders=function () {
        OrderService.getOrders(1)
        .success(function (ords) {
            if (angular.isArray(ords)) {
                $scope.Orders = ords;
                console.log("testing2");
                console.log("testing 3"+$scope.Orders);
            } else {
                $scope.Orders = [ords];
                console.log("testing");
            }

            $scope.dateT = true;
            $scope.StatusEnum = { 10: "Pending", 20: "Processing", 30: "Ready to Shipping", 40: "Cancelled" };

            // execute some code here (I'm making it up)
            $scope.currentPage = ords.currentPage;
            $scope.numPerPage = ords.numPerPage;
            // this will also trigger the watch you registered
            // or you can do what you do in watch callback here

        }).error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx to @theo about the success, I just put the $scope.$watch function into the success. Then it work.

```
  $scope.getOrders=function () {
            OrderService.getOrders(1)
            .success(function (ords) {
                if (angular.isArray(ords)) {
                    $scope.Orders = ords;
                    console.log("testing2");
                    console.log("testing 3"+$scope.Orders);
                } else {
                    $scope.Orders = [ords];
                    console.log("testing");
                }

                $scope.dateT = true;
                $scope.StatusEnum = { 10: "Pending", 20: "Processing", 30: "Ready to Shipping", 40: "Cancelled" };

               //Move the watch inside the success
                $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
                    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage), end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
                    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.Orders.slice(begin, end);
                    console.log("testing" + $scope.Orders);
                });
            }).error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
            });
        }
```

Comment: What happens if you call the `getOrders` function twice?